# Disable users button in C# server side

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, timer, textbox

This page is just with 3 textboxes, and 1 button.

txtUser: TextBox for username login

txtPassword: TextBox for the password login

txtRequest: A textbox where the user can type everything he wants

btnSubmit: A simple button used for login and create a txt file with the things typed in txtRequest..

Now, i need to find a way to disable the button, after the user submitted the request.
It needs to be disabled until 00:00 of the next day..

Example:

I go on the webpage, insert credentials in the two (username and pass) TextBox (Active Directory credentials) and type something in another TextBox, then click a "Submit button"

I was wondering.. What should i implement?

> ```
> public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
> {
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
>     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>
>         var username = txtUser.Text;
>         var oldPass = txtPassword.Text;
>
>         PrincipalContext _context = null;
>         try
>         {
>
>             _context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
>                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString(),
>                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchString"].ToString(),
>                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"].ToString(),
>                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString()
>                 );
>             UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_context, username);
>
>             if (user == null)
>             {
>                 lblError.Text = "Username e/o password non corretti";
>                 return;
>             }
>
>             bool isOldPassValid = false;
>
>             DateTime? PasswordExpDate;
>             if (user.LastPasswordSet != null)
>                 PasswordExpDate = ((DateTime)user.LastPasswordSet).AddDays(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordExpiresInDays"].ToString()));
>             else
>                 PasswordExpDate = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
>
>             if ((user.LastPasswordSet == null || PasswordExpDate < DateTime.UtcNow) && !user.PasswordNeverExpires)
>             {
>
>                 user.RefreshExpiredPassword();
>                 isOldPassValid = _context.ValidateCredentials(user.SamAccountName, oldPass);
>                 user.ExpirePasswordNow();
>             }
>             else
>                 isOldPassValid = _context.ValidateCredentials(user.SamAccountName, oldPass);
>
>             if (!isOldPassValid)
>             {
>                 lblError.Text = "Username e/o password non corretti";
>                 return;
>             }
>
>             //TUTTI I CHECK COMPLETI
>             string permessiread;
>             string permessiwrite;
>             lblError.Text = "Credenziali corrette, form inviato.";
>
>              /// SOMETHING HERE
>
>             if (boxread.Checked == true)
>             {
>                 permessiread = "SI";
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 permessiread = "NO";
>             }
>             if (boxwrite.Checked == true)
>             {
>                 permessiwrite = "SI";
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 permessiwrite = "NO";
>             }
>             string Richiesta = txtRequest.Text;
>             string data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
>             string spacer = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------";
>             string docPath = "C:\\Richieste\\";
>             string tot =
>                 "[ --- RICHIESTA PERMESSI --- ]" + "</br>" + "</br>" +
>                 "[ MESSAGGIO AUTOMATICO GENERATO DAL DOMAIN CONTROLLER DACA-I ]" + "</br>" +
>                 "[ Servizio richiesta permessi lettura/scrittura File-Server DACA-I ]" + "</br>" +
>                 "</br>" +
>                 "il giorno/ora        : " + data + "</br>" + "</br>" +
>                 spacer + "</br>" +
>                 "Percorso cartella: " + Richiesta + "</br>" + "</br>" +
>                 "Permessi lettura: " + permessiread + "</br>" +
>                 "Permessi scrittura: " + permessiwrite + "</br>";
>
>             using (System.IO.StreamWriter outputFile = System.IO.File.AppendText(docPath + "Richieste_permessi.txt"))
>             {
>                 outputFile.WriteLine(spacer);
>                 outputFile.WriteLine("il giorno/ora        : " + data);
>                 outputFile.WriteLine("Percorso cartella    : " + Richiesta);
>                 outputFile.WriteLine("Permessi scrittura   : " + permessiwrite);
>                 outputFile.WriteLine("Permessi lettura     : " + permessiread);
>             }
>         }
>         catch (PasswordException pex)
>         {
>             lblError.Text = "Error:  " + pex.Message;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             lblError.Text = string.Format("Errore: {0}, {1}, {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             if (_context != null)
>                 _context.Dispose();
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

That's a part of the code i tried.. and i think that's a stupid way tho, in fact it didn't work and i am gonna slap my-self, thanks for the support anyone

Comment: Not sure why you need timer for this!, after submit click don't you make call to server? isn't it right way to handle next actions on this page based on response from server instead of setting timer here.

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan cause i need the TextBox (or even the button) to be available every 4 hours..

Comment: How do you track the start time? and how do you persist it between page navigations?

Comment: @Zee I just edited the post to make it more "understandable" and sorry for bad English, i am italian :c

Comment: @h3llpr00f I posted an answer below, you'll have to figure out the code part.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

1. Add a Field in your Database under the Users Table called
   `PasswordUpdatedOn -> DateTime`
2. When the user updates the password set this field to `DateTime.Now`
3. On Page load & On the `btnSubmit_Click` Password update event
   , query the DB and check for this value. If
   `PasswordUpdateOn.AddDays(1) <= DateTime.Now` then Disable the text box.